# The parameter 'image' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'

Tags: flutter, constructor, null, this, nullable

I don't understand the issue with the following Code and would love to hear some ideas on how to solve my problem

Code:

```
class SplashContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashContent({
    Key? key,
    this.text,
    this.image,

  }) : super(key: key);
  final String text, image;
```

Comment: Add `required` keyword on both `text` and `image`

Answer (score 3):

While we are using `{}` on constructor, and it is known as `named paramter/Constructor`. By default, all parameters are optional here(named constructor). While we have  `final String text, image;`  and did not assign any value, it is showing the errors because of `null-safety`.

We need to add `required` before  `this.image,` like `required  this.image,`..

If you wish to accept null value, make those nullable like `String? file`. And be sure while using nullable value. Also, you can provide default value on constructor.